# ClickOnce Not Updating on Windows 7 Terminals

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have this bizarre scenario happened to me today morning. I was scheduled to publish a new version of my application and I did it successfully (as Visual Studio 2012 output said!). The Publish HTML also had the correct version in it.

> **Note**
>    - Development Terminal runs on Windows 7 SP1 with Visual Studio 2012 Update 4,
>      Crystal Reports 13 for Visual Studio and Kaspersky EndPoint Security 10 for Windows;
>    - Files are copied over a FTP to a Windows Server 2003 server within  the LAN;
>    - User Terminals are loaded with Windows 7 SP1 and Windows XP SP3 with Kaspersky EndPoint Security 10 for Windows;

When I checked with Users, some said new release weren't applied in their terminals. Further investigation revealed that those whom had Windows XP, had itself updated with the latest release, where as those whom had Windows 7 did not detect any updates available and runs the previous released version when ran without any errors.

Further, I noted that in Users who were having Windows 7, if the Application is Run from Start-up menu it loads the previous release which had been there earlier. I tried uninstalling and deleted all contents in

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0*

and launched the application from Publish.html web page again. Then I noticed that it prompts for installation and when I clicked "OK" it only installs an application with 6.95MB where as the new application is 7MB+. This proves that ClickOnce picks the previous release from some where, which I cant figure the location. I even tried up increasing the Publish Version thinking it will detect a signature change but did not. :(

I have checked the Manifest file in the server, it had the latest version specifying in it.

Let me know of any location where I could further investigate; I mean where does ClickOnce stores all files other than C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0* and where I could find the Log file which ClickOnce creates which I'm struggling to find

I have published releases earlier, but this is the first time I'm getting such problems. Since my last release which I publish, I had only installed Update 4 for Visual Studio.

Did anyone come across it?

These were my Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything worked today morning. It seems, some client level cache was a reason to this problem in Windows 7 users.

Should I have urged the users to re-start their machine, this would have not caused; I presume. But nevertheless happy that everything went on board with the new update.

Comment: Further investigation proved that the problem is not from VS nor ClickOnce rather its from the Proxy itself. Although we have set the "Bypass Local Address", we still need to put the FQIP address to the Proxy to disallow.